# Importing Alamofire.swift doesn't work

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to add alamofire to my project but I'm running into a problem.

Once I add the file into my project I can't compile, the errors I get are these:

```
Alamofire.swift:106:26: 'Method' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
Alamofire.swift:156:130: 'CFStringBuiltInEncodings' does not have a member named 'rawValue'
Alamofire.swift:245:61: Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type
Alamofire.swift:1290:90: Operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is 'NSString'
Alamofire.swift:1453:82: Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is 'NSURL'
```

Comment: Have follow the the installation explanation on Installation https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire? there are important to use alamofire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are either using an old version of Alamofire or an old version of Xcode. Make sure you are updated to the latest of both (HEAD of master, or 1.1.2 for Alamofire and Xcode 6.1.1 or 6.2.0 Beta 2)

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I was using the Xcode 6.0 instead of 6.1.1